# How is this proof for the scalar product rule of limits valid?

Tags: limits, proof-explanation

If we let $K=\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x),$
and let $c$ be a constant,

Then in order to show that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} cf(x) = cK$,
we must show that there is an $\epsilon$ for every $\delta$ such that

$\lvert cf(x)-cK \rvert < \epsilon$ whenever $\lvert x-a \rvert < \delta$.

The proof claims to prove this by staing:

$$\lvert cf(x)-cK \rvert = \lvert c \rvert \lvert f(x)-K \rvert < \lvert c \rvert  \frac{\epsilon}{\lvert c \rvert} = \epsilon.$$

However, I don't see how this proves anything other than basic manipulation of terms, and I don't see how it relates $\epsilon$ to $\delta$ in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **every** value of $\varepsilon>0,$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x) - K|<\varepsilon.$

What does **“every”** mean?

For **every** positive number $\varepsilon$, blah blah blah etc. is true of $\varepsilon.$

Is $\varepsilon/|c|$ a positive number?

If so then blah blah blah etc. is true of $\varepsilon/|c|.$

Thus there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-K| < \dfrac \varepsilon {|c|}.$

(This generally requires a smaller value of $\delta$ than what would be needed if we'd just wanted $|f(x)-K|<\varepsilon.$ But we know that such a value of $\delta$ exists because of the word "every".)

And then go through the rest of the argument.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, since $K$ has been defined to exist and be $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x),$ then it has already been proven that there is a $\epsilon$ for every $\delta$ where $\lvert f(x)-K \rvert < \epsilon$ whenever $\lvert x-a \rvert < \delta$.  So you define the new $\epsilon$ to be the old $\epsilon$ over $\lvert c \rvert$, so then there has to be a new $\delta$ for it because it is a positive number?  Is there a way to find the relation between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, or do we just know that they exist?

Comment: No. Not that there is an $\varepsilon$ for every $\delta,$ but the other way around: there is a $\delta$ for every $\varepsilon. \qquad$

Comment: The relationship between $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ depends on which function $f$ it is. And on which number $a$ is. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

The step missing is saying "So take $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-K|<\epsilon/|c|$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$. Thus, that $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ will work to show that $|cf(x)-cK|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$."

Most of the time, this step is left out of proof involving limits since it has the same flavor and is largely the same every time.

One other thing worth mentioning is that this proof doesn't work when $c=0$, but that exceptional case is rather trivial since it just leads to the claim that $\lim_{x \to a}{0}=0$.